# How to do a cronjob every 5 minutes between 00:05 and 23:55

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to schedule my crontab to execute a command EVERY 5 MINUTES between 00:05 and 23:55. I'm kinda new to cron, and I'm struggling to find the right way to do this... For now, I only found out how to do it between hours, not hours and minutes. Like, I know I can do it like this if I wanted to execute the command every 5 minutes between 00:00 and 23:00: `*/5 0-23 * * *`

But I want to execute it every 5 minutes between 00:05 and 23:55. How do I do that? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to execute a job every five minutes, every hour of the day, except for at exactly midnight.

You would schedule two jobs:

```
5-55/5  0-23  *  *  *
0       1-23  *  *  *
```

The first job would trigger every five minutes from `hh:05` through to `hh:55` every hour from `00` through to `23`. This job skips every full hour.

The second job would trigger on the hour, every hour from `01:00` through to `23:00`, but not at midnight. This would take care of the on-the-hour jobs that the first schedule skips.

See also: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Okay, this rly looks like what I need, I'll try that and have a proper answer if it worked tomorrow :)
Thank you very much! I'll be sure to come back here to accept the answer